# Fragments inside swipe views rather than just views Android

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, android-actionbar, swipeview

I have been using this link to implement my two screen tabbed view,

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

but my problem currently is that this demo only shows how to implement separate views on each tab such as a single TextView on each, whereas I wish to implement separate fragments on each tab that can interact with each other. For example, if a button is clicked on one fragment, I want it to change the text of a TextView on another fragment in the separate tab.

Currently I am using ONE fragment to implement both views and this is becoming complicated, because I can only do modifications to a certain view in the actual inflater of the view in the onCreateView method, rather than in the entire class.

So basically I want to separate them into 2 fragments and have them be able to interact with each other, but I am not sure how to configure them in the onCreateView method to work with the demo in the link I provided.

Thank you for any assistance you may have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach individual `Fragment` instances as pages of a `ViewPager` (instead of just simple views) using the `FragmentPagerAdapter` ([docs link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html)).

Comment: Yea I think that may be it, for some reason I was confused about how it would work but makes much more sense now. Must have just needed someone else to explain some. haha thanks!